# What word can I use to describe the process of something becoming hollow?

Tags: science

For example, if a solid metal rod is drilled down its longitudinal axis, the result will be a hollow cylinder.

"The cylinder underwent... [blank]"

In developmental biology, solid cords of endothelial cells undergo a process whereby they form a hollow cylindrical tube.

"The endothelial cells underwent LUMENIZATION"

....but I'm hoping for a more general term to describe this.

Comment: It underwent *hollowing out*.

Comment: Are you looking for a term from biology, or something more general?

Comment: @HotLicks your comment is still the best answer ;)

Comment: _hollowing_ without the _out_ might work in a technical context

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I guess I'm looking for a **general** term, but one that indicates the object is forming the hollowed space on its own (i.e. without outside influence - **boring**, **shelling**.  Therefore, "undergoing **cavitation**" seems to be the best answer. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'For example, if a solid metal rod is drilled down its longitudinal axis, the result will be a hollow cylinder."

The cylinder underwent...

> [**cavitation**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cavitation) - the formation of an empty space within a solid object or body.
>
> **[excavation](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/excavation)** - a cavity formed by cutting, digging, or scooping
>
> **[gouging](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gouging)** - to cut a deep hole in (something); to make (a deep hole) in something

Comment: I think **cavitation** seems to work nicely. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With regard to the cylinders of an engine, typically an engine modified for use in car racing,  the terminology is that the engine was **bored out** from 1071cc to 1275cc", for example, or whatever increase in cylinder capacity is doable (British UK English). As an alternative, **to ream** is the verb from the noun **reamer**, a cutting tool used in engineering to enlarge holes in a metal object such as a tube or pipe. So one might say that the metal tube should be **reamed** to improve the flow of liquid, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The 3D CAD program *SolidWorks* calls this process **shelling**. Typically it would change a 3D object into a hollow object (by default with a constant wall thickness), so a cylinder would become a cup or a tube.

The meaning is perfectly clear in the CAD context, but I would use "hollowing out" in a more general case- we don't want the reader to think of bombarding with artillery or shucking their nuts.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest 'decoring'.  It may not be in every dictionary, but it has widespread use in engineering etc to mean what you describe.

http://www.yourdictionary.com/decore

https://www.google.co.nz/search?num=100&espv=2&q=decoring

Comment: Actually, *coring* (as with an apple) would be more idiomatic.

Comment: "decoring" is not present in any other dictionary, except for the one you noted, which almost anyone can edit.  It's either not a real word, or recently made-up jargon.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not.  It is used plenty in engineering though.  And you can buy 'decoring' machines.  'Coring' isn't bad either, I guess, though I feel 'decoring' makes what you're actually doing a little more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Smooth muscle cells undergo a **cylindrical structural arrangement** forming a live hollow cylinder.  Endothelial cells then start to line such cylinder forming the endothelial wall, which is the innermost layer of a blood vessel. The endothelial cells do not cavitate and form a cylinder.  They just line the interior of an already formed cylindrical structure which is the adventitia.

> - [**cylindrical**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cylindric) - (adj) -  "having the shape of a cylinder"

As a matter of fact, you're looking for **"tubularization"** which is not what occurs with endothelial cells.

> - [**tubularization**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tubularization) - "the organization of tissue into the forms of tubes"

Answer (score 0):

The cylinder could have undergone a "boring." It was bored.

[Bore](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bore): 1. to pierce with a turning or twisting movement of a tool
2.to make (as a cylindrical hole) by boring or digging away material

Comment: I believe that the sentence "It was bored" would be improved if one added the word "out" as in, It was bored out, the "it" referring to the cylinder.